# Crear registros en una tabla HTML

Tags: javascript

Que tal estoy aprendiendo a programar con secuencia de comandados y quisiera realizar la consulta de información de una hoja de datos a HTML, pero no consigo realizarlo. Intente realizar lo mismo que esta en esta secuencia crear la tabla y después insertar los datos pero no lo consigo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

<script>

   function mostrar(id,id2,id3){

          var division = document.getElementById(id); //se define la variable "el" igual a nuestro div
          var indice = document.getElementById(id2).selectedIndex;
          if( indice > 0 ){
              division.style.display = ''; //damos un atributo display:none que oculta el div
              var ss = SpreadsheetApp
              .openById("")
              .getSheetByName("Mantenimiento correctivo");
               var ultimoRegistro = ss.getLastRow()+1;
               var data = ss.getRange(1,ultimoRegistro).getValue();
               var tabla = document.getElementById(id3);
          }
          else
          {
               division.style.display = 'none'; 
          }    
        }       
   }

 </script>

<!--<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  -->
  <body  bgcolor="e3e5e8">

<br><br>

<div align="center" >

<select id="option" name="nombre_area">
<option value="">Selecciona opción</option>
<option value="1">Administración</option>
<option value="2">Vestidores Mujeres</option>
<option value="3">Alberca</option>
</select>

<br>


<button id="buscar" onClick="mostrar('Mostrar_Tabla','option','Consulta')">Buscar</button>
<br><br><br>
</div>
<center>
<div id="Mostrar_Tabla" style="display:none">
<table border="1" id="Consulta">
        <caption>Consulta de solicitudes de mantenimiento</caption>
        <tr>
        <th>Area</th>
            <th>Folio</th>
            <th>Tema</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Fecha de registro</th>
            <th>Fecha de fin</th>
            <th>Estatus</th>
            <th>Autorización</th>
            <th>Fuera de servicio</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</center>

<!--
</body>
</html>
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el codigo que has subido, no puedo ver tu codigo html, pero supongamos que la definicion de la tabla es la siguiente

```
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Dni</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody  id="body-id" align="center">
                                </tbody>
```

Presta atencion, a que las tablas Html cuentan de dos partes, el encabezado (titulos de las columnas) se declaran entre las etiquetas `<thead></thead>`indicando cada columna con `<th>Nombre de tu columna</th>`.

Otra parte, muy importante es el `<tdboy>` donde se anexaran las filas de la tabla. Es necesario declarale un id, para poder refenciarlas con javascript o jquery segun lo que te sea mas facil.

Ahora supongamos, que tenes una funcion (que de alguna forma recibe parametros)

```
funcion cargarFilas(dni)
{
      //armo la celda
      celdaDni = '<td>'+ dni +'</td>';
      //armo la fila
      fila = '<tr>' + celdaDni + '</tr>'; 
      //con javascript creo el renglon
      var renglon = document.createElement('TR');
      //a ese renglon creado, le paso fila
      //con innerHTML puedes modificar la pagina, agregando texto o otras caracteristicas
      renglon.innerHTML = fila;
      //usando el id, accedo al body de la tabla y con appendchild le agrego la nueva fila
      document.getElementById('body-id').appendChild(renglon);
}
```

Espero que te sea util, cualquier consulta lo vamos viendo.